# Multiple main classes with SBT assembly

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly, sbt-plugin

I'm looking to create jars for AWS Lambda to run job tasks. Currently my build.sbt file looks something like this:

```
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(...)

lazy val core = project
    .settings(commonSettings: _*)

lazy val job = project
    .settings(commonSettings: _*)
    .dependsOn(core)

lazy val service = project
    .settings(commonSettings: _*)
    .settings(
        mainClass in assembly := Some("io.example.service.Lambda"),
        assemblyJarName in assembly := "lambda.jar"
    )
    .dependsOn(core)
```

Running `sbt assembly` assembles the `service` module into a jar for my API and that works fine. The module `job` however will have multiple `Main` classes (one pr. job) and when I run `sbt assembly job` the `service` module is also assembled (even through its not depended on).

How can I configure my setup to only assemble the `job` module when needed, and specify individual mainClasses as separately assembled jars?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `mainClass in assembly` in `job` to define which main class to use, and run `job/assembly` to just assemble the job assembly jar.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. That works for only assembling the job module how could I configure sbt to use multiple mains generating a jar each?

Comment: Easiest way would to create multiple projects that depend on `job`, and then either each containing their own main (no config necessary) or each configuring their main - which is defined the `job` project.

Comment: @DaleWijnand is there and example of this somewhere?

Comment: @CpILL here's one I found on GitHub: https://github.com/non/zillionaire/blob/95327d8b5f8adfd55d17d10d5cfa0a446b2b8159/build.sbt#L7

Answer (score 0):

You will need to override the default main class at build time by setting the property explicitly.

`sbt "; set mainClass in assembly := Some("another/class"); job/assembly"`

Not sure it's good practice but alternatively you can define a sub-project for each job with the correct main class set.

```
lazy val job1 = project
    .settings(commonSettings: _*)
    .settings(
        mainClass in assembly := Some("io.example.service.Lambda"),
        assemblyJarName in assembly := "lambda.jar"
    )
    .dependsOn(core)

lazy val job2 = project
    .settings(commonSettings: _*)
    .settings(
        mainClass in assembly := Some("io.example.service.Lambda2"),
        assemblyJarName in assembly := "lambda2.jar"
    )
    .dependsOn(core)
```